# ng-options: how to put empty option at the end?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I've got something like this (simplified):

```
<select ng-model=model.policyHolder ng-options="person.index as person.name for person in model.insurance.persons">
  <option value>Someone else
</select>
```

This creates a dropdown with options for person names and an empty one for "someone else" at the top. The question is, how do I get that empty option **at the bottom** of the dropdown?

I would very much like to keep using `ng-options` for this, especially since controlling the position of the default option seems like too small a change to justify the slightly more verbose `<option ng-repeat>` way.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to just have a value="" option at the end, or do you want a blank input field, that is only visible or active when Someone else is selected?

Comment: An empty <option>, yes. But I want it *at the bottom*, where by default it is inserted at the top.

Answer (score 5):

use option with `value=""`

Like:

```
<select ng-model="model.policyHolder" ng-options="person.index as   person.name for person in model.insurance.persons">
  <option value="">Someone else</option>
</select>
```

If you want to show **Someone else** at the bottom when click on drop-down list you can use.

```
<select ng-model="model.policyHolder">
    <option ng-repeat="person in model.insurance.persons" value="{{person.index}}">{{person.name}}</option>
    <option value="">Someone else</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what was happening, but I couldn't get the `ng-repeat` way to work properly. It seems to keep selecting the value or something, which is why I went for the `ng-options` notation. But seriously, is that the only way? I seems like such a mundane thing to have the empty option at the bottom...

Comment: I edited my code. please  use `ng-model="model.policyHolder"` in `select ` list not in `option` for bellow portion code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to add an element at the top, not the bottom.

If you want something at the end of the list, you could always add it in the JavaScript.

See working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xeIJSJ4OvrsDzJobssWX?p=preview), adapted from the angular [select documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Main part copied below:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ],
     selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
     };

     // Add the alternative option
     // may need to use $digest, depending on where in the process you do this.
      $scope.data.availableOptions.push({ id: '', name: 'None of the above'})
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```